# Lazy-install of npm dependencies?

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

As a bit of background for my reasoning around this request:
I have created a set of Gulp based tasks and have packaged them in a NPM styled package.  Having this package allows me to import my tasks into my future projects so that I don't need to be copying and pasting my Gulp tasks around between them.  I have this working great.

The issue that I currently have is that I am creating a fairly wide and generic set of tasks that can service a array of web project configurations.  I don't use all of these tasks in every project, but when installing my Gulptools package I end up getting all of it's dependencies installed.  Currently at 250mb worth, but I expect this to increase with age,

It would be really great if I could do some sort of lazy dependency installation, that would pull and install my package's dependencies when they are first required during runtime.  Subsequent requests would be much faster then as the dependency would be installed.

Does anyone know how to do this?  If so, you are awesome! :)

---

**Update 1**

I have found the following package!

https://www.npmjs.com/package/lazy-install

I will investigate this and report. :)